# Absolute Radio Frequency Channel Number (ARFCN) in android device

Tags: android

I want to fetch  Absolute Radio Frequency Channel Number (ARFCN) of the android.
As pe my knowledge ;-Absolute Radio Frequency Channel Number (ARFCN) is a unique number given to each radio channel in GSM. The ARFCN can be used to calculate the exact frequency of the radio channel.

Can any one please help me.hoe to get this.

IS there any API or some library available?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like it's possible to retrieve the ARFCN using public APIs in Android. Please refer to this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/tVyNMnXtcEI) on android-platform Google groups.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! is it possible by using any 3rd party API or anything?

Comment: Since the platform does not provide any support, it would not be possible to find a solution that would work on all the devices, though you may be able to find a solution that works on rooted phones.

Comment: i dont agree with you . we can retrieve ARFCN using public api . first call getAllcellInfo.get(0) and using if-else and instanceof check which is : CellInfoGSM or CellInfoCDMA or CellInfoLTE or ... and then cast to it and call getarfcn() or get getearfcn() or ...

Comment: @ofskyMohsen this only works on API 24 and higher, do you know any way I can get this information with API lower than 23?

Comment: @Keselme In API lower than 23 (Android 6.0) it isn't possible to access to ARFCN.

Comment: @ofskyMohsen is there any workaround prior to 24 on un-rooted devices?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the where you can get the info how you can get the arfcn on your android phone [how to get arfcn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917049/telephony-parameters-not-available-through-framework-apis/15656995#15656995)