# Telephony parameters not available through framework APIs

Tags: android, android-ndk, telephony, modem, at-command

I have to fetch the info related to following Telephony parameters: BCCH, Band, DL ARFCN,UL ARFCN, BLER, MOS DL, MOS UL, Txpwr & Handover Parameters.

I searched a lot but didn't find any way to get this information through APIs. There may be some other ways (I am not sure), like:

1. Using AT command.
2. Using AIDL, talk to RIL & fetch the info.
3. Using NDK, write c code which will directly talk to modem/low level implementation.

But I don't know which is the right way or how to proceed with the right approach. Any help regarding any of the Telephony parameters will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey guys, I didn't get any info yet. Did u ever come across such requirement then plz share ur experience. Here in post of Joao MG, https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/tVyNMnXtcEI it is mentioned about the calculation of ARFCN, Band etc but I didn't get how to call or implement it. Can anyone plaese elaborate if possible.

Comment: did you find a way to do it?