# Get UARFCN and SC in Android

Tags: android

How can I dynamically read low level UMTS (3G) network information: UARFCN (Absolute Radio Frequency Channel Number) and SC (Scrambler Code) in Android. Is it possible at all?

Comment: See if this thread helps you: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/tVyNMnXtcEI

Comment: install app CellMapper and you can see these numbers . You can reach these numbers using TelephonyManager.

Answer (score 1):

In GSM , WCDMA and LTE you can access ARFCN using API :

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CellInfo ci = tm.getAllCellInfo.get(0) ; // Registered Cell Tower

if (ci instanceof CellInfoGSM)
{
 ((CellInfoGSM)ci).getCellIdentity().getArfcn();
}
else if (ci instanceof CellInfoWCDMA)
{
 ((CellInfoWcdma)ci).getCellIdentity().getUarfcn();
}
else if (ci instanceof CellInfoLte)
{
 ((CellInfoLte)ci).getCellIdentity().getEarfcn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several people who have asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010618/absolute-radio-frequency-channel-number-arfcn-in-android-device) and [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-platform/129s31hx97/writing-an-app-in-android-to-get-the-arfcn-from-the-mobile-network) and some in XDA Forums(*XDA Links not allowed*).

I don't think there are any public API's to access it, But however you can use `TelephonyManager` to get some basic information about the telephony services like `IMEI` or something like that but not  **UARFCN** or **SC**

There are some apps available on playstore like [ARFCN Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aprender.arfcncalculator), [ARFCN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ARFCN) or [UARFCN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UARFCN)  these might help you to understand it

You can [decompile](http://yeblon.com/how-to-decompile-android-apk-app-files) or [Reverse engineer](https://kkinder.com/2011/11/27/so-you-want-to-reverse-engineer-an-android-app-apk/) these apps and check if you get some information from it